# OpenGL Geometry Shader rendering triangle instead of square from a point

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-3

I am trying to render a square from a single point, here is my geometry shader code:

```
#version 330 core
layout (points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices=4) out;

void main(){
    vec4 pos=gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    gl_Position=pos+vec4(1,1,0,0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position=pos+vec4(1,-1,0,0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position=pos+vec4(-1,-1,0,0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position=pos+vec4(-1,1,0,0);
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Vertex shader looks like this:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location=0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 model;

void main(){
    gl_Position=projection*view*model*vec4(position,1.0);
}
```

It only renders a triangle, I'm not sure why it only renders a triangle.

Comment: When I do this, there is nothing displayed, I do have face culling enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertices define a [triangle strip](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Triangle_primitives). Every group of 3 adjacent vertices forms a triangle and the winding order is defined by the winding of the first triangle (successive triangles have reversed order). When [face culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling) is enabled, you need to care about the winding order. The default winding order of front faces is counter clockwise. Therefore you have to swap the 1st and 2nd vertex:

```c
void main(){
    vec4 pos=gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    gl_Position=pos+vec4( 1, -1, 0, 0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position=pos+vec4( 1,  1, 0, 0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position=pos+vec4(-1, -1, 0, 0);
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position=pos+vec4(-1,  1, 0, 0);
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}
```